# How to feed 64 input and only one output to MLP neural network with newff funchtion in matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have a `8x8` matrix (I make this matrix to a vector of `1x64`) and want to feed it to MLP neural network and have a 1 hidden layer with 10 perceptron and only one output.

How could I use [`newff`](http://dali.feld.cvut.cz/ucebna/matlab/toolbox/nnet/newff.html)  for doing this?
I don't know how to feed it to network??

Thanks, K.A.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using the 'nntool' command, to start working with the neural network toolbox GUI. There you can select the kind of neural network you want which I believe is "feed-forward backprop".

It is difficult to help, because you gave really little information.

I suggest that you take a look to the neural network toolbox webinars:
http://www.mathworks.com/products/neural-network/webinars.html

I have chopped some code from one assignment I did in the past, I hope it works for you:

```
    % MLP building
    net = newff(minmax(InputData),[NumNeuron 1],{'tansig' 'purelin'},'trainlm');
    % MLP training
    [net,tr]=train(net,InputData,TargetData);
    % answer
    output_from_network = sim(net,InputData);
```

The newff command gets the dimmensionality of your inputData directly from the sample input you give. The minmax its supposed to help Matlab to set the initial values of your NN weights. NumNeuron will fix the number of neurons in your hidden layer. And the cell {'tansig' 'purelin'} fixes the types of activation functions you will use for the hidden and output layers respectively.

Hope this helps,